# Struts2 - See real destination url in browser on action result

Tags: url, redirect, struts2, action

In Struts2, when returning from a successful action, I want the user browser to show to the user the real url he is navigating into, and not the original call to action. As far as I understand, **I cannot use a type="redirect"** action because I need to pull the action results from the value stack.

Let's say, for example, if I define an action to save a new element in my db, and then I want to take the user to see the whole list of elements...:

```
     <action name="doSavePage" class="FbPageAdmin" method="doSavePage" >
        <result name="input">/pageadmin.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/pageadmin.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/pageList.jsp</result>
     </action>
```

If the action finishes successfully, I want the user to see **mysite.com/pageList.jsp**, and **not mysite.com/doSavePage.action**

Is that possible?

Thanks everybody in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to have the JSP file name shown?

In any case, I'm not sure I understand; if you want to show a listing of objects after adding one, redirect to the "list" action (and/or method). You should do a redirect after a POST anyway (the post-redirect-get pattern) to avoid resubmitting the same form data on a refresh.

Also, ideally, JSPs should live under /WEB-INF to disallow direct aclient access.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! As you are saying I've already been reading something about the problems with re-submits... I'll have to give that other pattern a try.

Comment: By the way, about not hiding urls, let me tell you that in many contexts it's crucial to take care of it (as it's also important not to use GET parameters if possible). One example of the importance of all these things is SEO-friendly-urls. I've already read a couple of threads in this forum about "Struts2 + SEO-friendly-urls", but they address the problem of mapping action-calls against seo friendly urls, they don't seem to solve destination-urls matters. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1125414 Not sure what you mean by "destination URLs". In any case, there are a number of options for creating RESTful URLs in S2, notably the REST plugin, or a [pattern matcher](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/wildcard-mappings.html#WildcardMappings-Parametersinnamespaces).

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers! Finally, after checking some of the options you mention here and some others I found in this same site, I found a solution which doesn't use any extra Plugin or Interceptor. As I think it could be helpful for others, and as it was quite long to write it down here, I decided to write my own post about it (http://www.errorhell.com/2012/01/seo-friendly-urls-with-struts-2-search-example/).

There you won't see any "magic", but if you read it all through, you'll see that it covers some aspects which are maybe not solved by the REST Plugin or the Convention Plugin.

Comment: @fernando Glad you got it working, but you really re-invented stuff that already exists in the framework using a variety of mechanisms, even w/o the plugins.

Comment: Thanks @dave_newton! But could you please tell me one? I'd like to see a working example which shows me seo-friendly URLs all the time, even on form submits. And if you say we don't need any plugin, much better! Maybe using Interceptors?

Comment: @fernando The only reason the parameters show up in the URL in because it's a GET request; for a user search the URL presentation doesn't matter. Look at the [wildcard mappings](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/wildcard-mappings.html) docs in the "Advanced Wildcards" section for some nice straight-to-parameter mapping options.

Comment: @dave_newton. Thanks for the reference on the Advanced Options of the Wildcard Mappings. It gives a lot of flexibility at interpreting incoming URLs. In my blog-post, in fact,  I'm using a simple version of Wildcard Mappings. About the other point, let me say that it's **really important** to get SEO friendly submit URLs (specially search results). Not only because of bookmarking and sharing; also, because **you'll include the whole list of your SEO friendly search-result-URLs in your sitemap.xml file**. Thats needed for Google (and others) SEO efforts. (ie:http://www.opodo.co.uk/sitemap.xml)

Comment: And one last thing: No. You don't want two have two different URL versions of the same search results. One with GET params (for the browser) and another one being SEO friendly (for sitemap.xml). That only takes you to be punnished by Google because of content-duplicity)

Comment: @fernando Actually not true, but separate issue. I know what a site map is. And as I said, there's any number of ways to avoid parameters in the URL.